# Get asp label value and put in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, pie-chart

I have two label and I want to get the value and store in javascript function. 
I want the value to put in pie chart label. Im only getting one and I don't know how to do it in another label. Please Help me.

Here is what I have so far.

**Javascript **

```
    var pie = 0;
    function changepie(val) {
        pie = val;
    }
    var pie2 = 0;
    function changepie2(val) {
          pie2 = val;
      }
```

**Front end**

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"?</asp:Label>
 <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
```

**Another javascript for pie chart loading**

```
 window.onload = function () {
            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
            {
                animationEnabled: true,
                animationDuration: 1300,
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                legend: {
                    verticalAlign: "bottom",
                    horizontalAlign: "center"
                },
                data: [
                {

                    indexLabelFontSize: 10,
                    indexLabelFontWeight: "bold",
                    indexLabelFontFamily: "Helvetica",
                    indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
                    indexLabelLine: "none",
                    radius: "100%",
                    type: "pie",

                    toolTipContent: "{y} - <strong>#percent%</strong>",
                    dataPoints: [
                        { y: pie, legendText: "", 
                                    label: pie + "%", 
                                    indexLabelLineColor: "#1dc7ea", 
                                    indexLabelFontColor: "#1dc7ea", 
                                    exploded: true, 
                                    indexLabelPadding: "5px"
                                    },
                        { y: pie2, legendText: "",
                                    label: pie2, 
                                    indexLabelLineColor: "#FF4A55", 
                                    indexLabelFontColor: "#FF4A55" 
                                    }

                    ]
                }
                ]
            });
            chart.render();
        }
```

**and here is my backend**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Label1.Text = Session("percent").ToString.Replace("<span class>", "").Replace("</span>", "")
    Label2.Text = Session("aaa").ToString
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "Script", "changepie(" + Label1.Text + ");", True)
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "Script", "changepie2(" + Label2.Text + ");", True)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

in **changepie** function use this

```
    var label1= 0;
        function changepie(lbael1,label2) {

             var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
            {
                animationEnabled: true,
                animationDuration: 1300,
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                legend: {
                    verticalAlign: "bottom",
                    horizontalAlign: "center"
                },
                data: [
                {

                    indexLabelFontSize: 10,
                    indexLabelFontWeight: "bold",
                    indexLabelFontFamily: "Helvetica",
                    indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
                    indexLabelLine: "none",
                    radius: "100%",
                    type: "pie",

                    toolTipContent: "{y} - <strong>#percent%</strong>",
                    dataPoints: [
                        { y: lbael1+", ", legendText: "", 
                                    label: pie + "%", 
                                    indexLabelLineColor: "#1dc7ea", 
                                    indexLabelFontColor: "#1dc7ea", 
                                    exploded: true, 
                                    indexLabelPadding: "5px"
                                    },
                        { y: label2, legendText: "",
                                    label: pie2, 
                                    indexLabelLineColor: "#FF4A55", 
                                    indexLabelFontColor: "#FF4A55" 
                                    }

                    ]
                }
                ]
        }


----------
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Label1.Text = Session("percent").ToString.Replace("<span class>", "").Replace("</span>", "")
    Label2.Text = Session("aaa").ToString
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "Script", "changepie(" + Label1.Text + "," + Label2.Text + ");", True)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer gonna give it a try. But I want the two label to stored in separate to like this. { y: label1val } { y: label2val }

Comment: Madaliar. Tried your solution but its not working. All i want to do is to get the label value and stored in pie chart label. Do you have any idea to make it work? Thank you.

Comment: Store label texts in an array and pass it to changepie function.You can extract the values from array by indexing and storing it in respective label variables.This is what i did.What error did u get?

Comment: Theirs no error. Is that just the other value is not displaying. Only one value. I actually render the label value when the user click the gridview row.

Comment: Edited my codes above so that you can see what I want to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: Ur trying to call change pie function seperately for each label.This will fetch u only one label.Trying putting your chart code  inside changepie function and pass both label one text and label two text in one function call.
 ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "Script", "changepie(" + Label1.Text + ","+Label2.Text+");", True) and then fetch both these values in function as param and store in label one and label two variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122374/discussion-between-yuvraj-mudaliar-and-xtian).

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm sorry I am new in Javascript. Please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You ned to make sure if

```
RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "Script", "changepie(" + Label1.Text + ");", True)
```

is getting called then you simply need to parseto int

using

```
Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text)
```